# trying to give a redshift user access to an IAM role, trusted entity list was updated but still getting the same error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-iam

Error message: User "arn:aws:redshift:us-west-2:123456789012:dbuser:my-cluster/user2" is not authorized to assume IAM Role "roleArn"

on the role I've updated the trust policy to this which should allow the assume role, what am I messing up here?

```
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "redshift.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
```

code is valid JSON had to cut off the rest.
I'm interning and new to IAM roles. if the redshift account also needs the permission update, how do I give it to them? I've been on this issue for a while so thanks to any help you can give.

Comment: What you you doing with this role? When are you getting the error? Do you want to use it with `LOAD`, `UNLOAD` or _Spectrum_?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use an IAM role with `LOAD` or `UNLOAD` operations one has to:

- create an IAM role with trust relationship with Redshift service
- attach the role to the cluster

You described doing the first step. Have you also attached the role? You can see the attached role in the AWS UI or list them with CLI:

```
aws redshift describe-clusters --cluster-identifier my-cluster --query 'Clusters[].IamRoles'

[
    [
        {
            "IamRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/my-redhift-role",
            "ApplyStatus": "in-sync"
        }
    ]
]
```

---

Looking at the error you're getting,

> Error message: User "arn:aws:redshift:us-west-2:123456789012:dbuser:my-cluster/user2" is not authorized to assume IAM Role "roleArn"

looks like in the operation you're issuing the role is wrongly configured. To me the error suggests that you're instructing Redshift to assume `roleArn` role, which probably does not exist. You should put your role name there.